# Problems in evaluating subgraphs of a graph

Tags: c++, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

Here is the question [link](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/depth-first-search/practice-problems/algorithm/easylife/).

> Given an undirected graph. Density of a graph is <sup>**|E|**</sup>⁄<sub>**|V|**</sub>. Your task is to choose non-empty set of vertices **V** such that subgraph induced on **V** has maximal density and print this density. But if maximal density is strictly greater than **1**, just print **">1"**.
>
> Maximum number of vertices: 10<sup>5</sup>
> Maximum number of edges: 10<sup>5</sup>

I just made a simple solution, but in this solution I can keep track of the whole graph, but how do I get the value of density for smaller subGraphs?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
vector<int> adj[1000002];               // adjacency lists adj for storing graph edges
int node=0;                              // initializing for node value(vertices)
bool visited[100001]={false};            // keeps track of visited nodes(vertices) 
int edge=-1;
int ans=-1;
int n;                                  // keeps optimum value of no. of nodes
int e;                                   // keeps optimum value of no. of edges
void dfs(int s)
{
    node++;
    edge++;
    if(edge>0)                           
    {
        float dummy=(float)edge/(float)node;
        if(dummy>ans)
            {ans=dummy;
             e=edge;
             n=node;
            }
    }
    visited[s]=true;
    int t;
    for(int i=0;i!=adj[s].size();i++)
    { t=adj[s][i];
        if(visited[t]==false)
        {
           dfs(t);
        }
    }


}
int main()
{
    long long v,ed,i,j,x,y;
    cin>>v>>ed;
    for(long long k=0;k<ed;k++)
    {
        cin>>x>>y;
        adj[x].push_back(y);
        adj[y].push_back(x);
    }
     if(ed>v)
        cout<<">1"<<endl;
    else{
    for(i=1;i<=v;i++)
    {
        if(visited[i]==false)
        {
            node=0;
            edge=-1;
            dfs(i);
            //cout<<e<<"/"<<n<<endl;
        }
    }
   
    cout<<e<<"/"<<n<<endl;}
}
```

Comment: You should clarify your question to get answers.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to get better result:

1.Do a dfs on each component to get the answer.

2.Avoid the floating point calculation you are doing and try all integer calculation.

3.No reason to use `long long` here with that range

Change the code to something like this should work:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
vector<int> adj[1000002];               // adjacency lists adj for storing graph edges
int node=0;                              // initializing for node value(vertices)
bool visited[100001]={false};            // keeps track of visited nodes(vertices) 
int edge=0;

void dfs(int s)
{
    node++;
    visited[s]=true;
    int t;
    edge+=adj[s].size();
    for(int i=0;i!=adj[s].size();i++)
    { 
        t=adj[s][i];
        if(visited[t]==false)
        {
           dfs(t);
        }

    }
}

int main()
{
    int v,ed,i,j,x,y;
    cin>>v>>ed;
    for(int k=0;k<ed;k++)
    {
        cin>>x>>y;
        adj[x].push_back(y);
        adj[y].push_back(x);
    }

    int mark[3]; mark[0]=mark[1]=mark[2]=0;
    int mx_node=0;
    for(i=1;i<=v;i++)
    {
        if(visited[i]==false)
        {
            node=0;
            edge=0;
            dfs(i);
            edge/=2;
            if(node>edge){ 
                mark[0]=1;
                mx_node=mx_node<node?node:mx_node;
            }
            else if(node==edge) mark[1]=1;
            else mark[2]=1;
        }
    }

    if(mark[2]) printf(">1\n");
    else if(mark[1]) printf("1\n");
    else printf("%d/%d\n",mx_node-1,mx_node);
}
```